# How to current array key inside foreach

Tags: php, arrays, foreach

In my PHP code I want to check inside foreach iteration what is the current array key (In code below: key1/key2/key3/key4/key5).

I have assoc array which looks like this:

var_dump($myArray);

array(5) {

["key1"]=> array(2) {....}

["key2"]=> array(2) {....}

["key3"]=> array(2) {....}

["key4"]=> array(2) {....}

["key5"]=> array(2) {....}

}

```
foreach($myArray as $key) {
    echo key($myArray);
}
```

For example this only returns: key1key1key1key1key1

My desired output should look like: key1key2key3key4key5

I've been searching for a while but I can't find any smart solution.

Thank you :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[PHP.net foreach documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.foreach.php)

```
foreach ($variable as $key => $value) {
  echo $key .':'. $value;
}
```